# What is the categorical setting for higher-level real analysis?

Tags: analysis, category-theory, meta-math

A lot of disciplines in higher-level mathematics can be summarized by describing what objects they study and in what setting they are studied in. For example,

- Topology is the study of topological spaces and is set in the category $\rm\bf Top$, since we consider its foundational objects to be topological spaces.
- Differential geometry is the study of smooth manifolds and is set in the intersection of the categories $\rm\bf Diff$ and $\rm\bf Vect$, since we consider two of its most foundational objects to be smooth manifolds and tangent spaces.

Analysis is strange; it seems there is no easy way to describe what is the most foundational setting that analysis can be done in. Perhaps restricting my question to real analysis that is done in a typical undergraduate course would be easier. Would it be correct to say that this type of analysis is done on $\mathbb R$ equipped with a metrizable topology and an inner product space structure?

My question is probably summed up in the following: how can we categorize the most typical types of analysis and in which categories they are set in?

Comment: Real analysis is the study of a specific object, namely the real numbers, rather than studying a category the real numbers live in. For example, one could define a category of ordered spaces with order preserving isomorphisms, and then study properties about ordered spaces since $\mathbb R$ is one such space, but you're no longer strictly doing real analysis. Category theory is for describing relationships between sets and not for understanding the internal structure of a specific set in terms of its elements. Point of this is, there's no relevant category; it's just the real numbers.

Comment: Analysis as a whole considers plenty of categories though... As a simple example, functional analysis has plenty of them (TVSs, Banach Spaces, Cauchy Spaces, etc). The difference is that these are classes of spaces studied in functional analysis, while in real analysis you only care about a single space.

Comment: If you think those "summaries" of topology and differential geometry convey any idea whatsoever about what those two disciplines do, you proba ly should go read a textbook about them!

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I agree that the real numbers are the central study of real analysis. However, my question was more trying to determine what exactly the structures that we give $\mathbb R$ in most analytic settings (i.e. $\mathbb R$ can be a topological space, vector space, normed vector space, group, smooth manifold, etc). I'm just trying to get a handle on what kinds of spaces are being thrown around when doing analysis.

Comment: We use *all* those properties. To again reiterate, the point of real analysis is to use all properties of $\mathbb R$. In particular, we often want to consider generic set functions on $\mathbb R$, so the only reasonable background category would be the category of Sets anyway (restricted to a single object in this case). Category theory isn't a silver bullet to explain and distinguish fields of maths, and shouldn't be treated as such... It's merely a (very, very) useful language for describing properties that families of objects or maps have in common